# How to make factory fiscal quarters behave like dates

Tags: r

I’m putting together some functions to help summarize temporal data in fiscal quarters. Function I have will take a date—e.g. `2017-01-01`—and spit out factored character value that corresponds—e.g. `”1Q2017”`. I’m using my data to create graphs in ggplot. But since I factor the quarters, I can’t use attributes like `geom_line()` to connect my data points, like you would for dates.

Can I create a data type for quarters that displays as quarters but behaves like dates? How would I do this?

Comment: See [`as.yearqtr` from the `zoo`-package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-0/topics/yearqtr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"yearqtr"` class in zoo represents year/quarters but acts sort of like dates in so far as internally such objects are represented numerically as year + frac where frac is 0, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4 and one can perform arithmetic on them and they format as meaningful year/quarter strings and work with lines in ggplot2 (and classic graphics and lattice graphics).  See `?yearqtr` and `?scale_x_yearqtr`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

# test data
dates <- c("2017-01-01", "2017-04-01")
values <- 1:2

z <- zoo(values, as.yearqtr(dates)) # test zoo object

# 1. classic graphics

plot(z, axat = "n") 
axis(1, at = time(z), labels = format(time(z), "%YQ%q"))

# 2. ggplot2 graphics

autoplot(z) + scale_x_yearqtr()

# 3. ggplot2 graphics using data frame with yearqtr

DF <- fortify.zoo(z) # test data frame
sapply(DF, class)
##     Index         z 
## "yearqtr" "integer" 

ggplot(DF, aes(Index, z)) + geom_line() + scale_x_yearqtr()
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the comment from @Jaap and incorporating with example graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

df <- data.frame(date1 = c("2017-01-01", "2016-10-01", "2016-07-01"),
                 v1 = c(2, 4, 3))
df$date1 <- as.Date(df$date1)

ggplot(df, aes(x = date1, y = v1)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(name = "quarters",
               date_labels = as.yearqtr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify `group=1` in `aes`.

```
library(tidyverse) # install.packages('tidyverse') if needed

dat = data_frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date('2017-01-01'), 
                                 as.Date('2017-12-31'), 
                                 length.out=365), 
                 x = rnorm(365))
dat = mutate(dat, qtr = paste0(lubridate::quarter(date), 'Q', lubridate::year(date)))
dat$qtr = as.factor(dat$qtr) # for similarity to your situation
dat %>%
    group_by(qtr) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(x)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=qtr, y=n, group=1)) +
    geom_line()
```